# MEEP cygwin install issue

Tags: cygwin, meep

I'm trying to install MEEP through cygwin, I have all the required packages installed, however when I run `./configure` I get the following error message:

```
configure: error: Couldn't find the required libctl library.
```

Even though the libctl package is definitely installed!

Comment: May be your library libctl is not accessible from the current path

Answer (score 1):

found off here

http://www.physics.uc.edu/~thang/mm-cygwin.txt
   Cygwin:

```
- Run Cygwin.exe and insntall Cygwin to  C:/cygwin
- Add g++, gnuplot, editting...packages


MEEP:

- Install guile (guile-1.8.3) (to /usr/local)
- Istall szip (szip-2.1) (to /usr/local)
- Install hdf5 (hdf5-1.6.6)
   -> /.configure --enable-cxx --with-szlib --prefix=/usr/local
      make
      make check (all tests must pass)
      make install
- Install h5utils (h5utils-1.10.1) (to /usr/local) (h5utils should see hdf5 library)
     --enable-cxx --with-szlib
- Install BLAS (to /usr/local)
     gunzip blas.tgz
     tar xf blas.tar
     f77 -c -O3 *.f   # compile all of the .f files to produce .o files
     ar rv libblas.a *.o    #  combine the .o files into a library
     su -c "cp libblas.a /usr/local/lib"   # switch to root and install
- Install lapack (lapack-3.1.1) (to /usr/local)
- Install harminv (harminv-1.3.1) (to /usr/local)
- Install libctl (libctl-3.0.2) (to /usr/local)
- Install meep (meep-1.10.1) (to /usr/local)
   -> /.configure --prefix=/usr/local (make sure that meep sees hdf5 library)
      make
      make check
      make install
```